# Unable to use python for Modeltime.gluonts in R

Tags: r, linux, docker, conda

I am building a docker image which will have `modeltime.gluonts` library in R.

I have installed miniconda using the following command in the dockerfile:

```
RUN R -e "reticulate::install_miniconda('/home/rstudio/miniconda/'); Sys.setenv(RETICULATE_MINICONDA_PATH = '/home/rstudio/miniconda/'); q(save = 'no')"
```

But whenever I try to load modeltime.gluonts library, it throws the following error:

```
> library(modeltime.gluonts)
Loading required package: modeltime
Could not detect any Conda Python Environments with `reticulate::conda_list()`. Conda is required for 'modeltime.gluonts'. Try using `reticulate::install_miniconda()`.
```

Actually, there is a conda environment ready on the image:

```
> library(reticulate)
> conda_list()
          name                                               python
1 r-reticulate /home/rstudio/miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python
> conda_binary()
[1] "/home/rstudio/miniconda/bin/conda"
> conda_python()
[1] "/home/rstudio/miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python"
> conda_version()
[1] "conda 4.9.2"
> py_config()
python:         /home/rstudio/miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python
libpython:      /home/rstudio/miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/libpython3.6m.so
pythonhome:     /home/rstudio/miniconda/envs/r-reticulate:/home/rstudio/miniconda/envs/r-reticulate
version:        3.6.12 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Dec  9 2020, 00:36:02)  [GCC 9.3.0]
numpy:          /home/rstudio/miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy
numpy_version:  1.19.4

python versions found: 
 /home/rstudio/miniconda/envs/r-reticulate/bin/python
 /home/rstudio/miniconda/bin/python3
 /usr/bin/python3
 /home/rstudio/miniconda/bin/python
```

I have tried the following:

> 1. Change miniconda location

> 2. Install miniconda by directly downloading from the terminal.

> 3. `Sys.setenv(GLUONTS_PYTHON = 'path/to/python')`

> 4. `modeltime.gluonts::install_gluonts()`

I am using `rocker/verse` base image.

I have no idea what is causing this error.
Can someone help me with this, please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whenever I was trying to use `r-gluonts` environment, it was not being set as default. Reticulate was still referring `r-reticulate` environment as a default environment.

So I had to remove `r-reticulate` explicitly through `conda` and set path for `GLUONTS_PYTHON="path/to/gluonts/enviroment"`

Answer (score 0):

this worked for me:

```
reticulate::use_miniconda("~/Library/r-miniconda/envs/r-gluonts/bin/python")
```